# How can I access value from pointer inside pointer on query with Parse in swift?

Tags: swift, pointers, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

How can I access value from pointer inside pointer on query with Parse in swift?

This has to do with three classes in Parse. One is called Post_Story, on is Post and one is User. When I query for Post_Story i am able to retreive pointer info from a key "Post", but is there any way to access information from a pointer within that pointer? (key "createdBy" to User class)

My code looks like this:

```
       let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post_Story")
    postQuery.whereKey("story", containedIn: storyObjects)
    postQuery.includeKey("post")

    postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                if let postL = object["post"] as? PFObject {

                    if postL["createdBy"] != nil {

                        //this is where I want to get infor from PFUser, but not all info is sent
                        print((postL["createdBy"] as! PFUser)) //prints PFUser object without username etc.

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {}
    }
```

I hope the question is not too stupid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `postQuery.includeKey("post.createdBy")` to include the user object in the `createdBy` column of `post`.